# Waypoint missions with postive gimbal pitch (angled upwards)

Tags: dji-sdk

Unfortunately the DJI SDK does not allow to angle the gimbal upwards with the waypoint mission (See [SDK Doc: DJI Waypoint Gimbal Pitch](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypoint.html#djiwaypoint_gimbalpitch_inline)).

As a workaround, one may use [DJI Gimbal.rotate()](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Gimbal/DJIGimbal.html?search=gimbal&i=1&#djigimbal_rotategimbalwithrotation_inline) to send upward looking gimbal commands during flight. Unfortunately for the Mavic 2 this is not working anymore when doing non-curved waypoint missions (likely bug in Mavic 2 firmware).

My question

1. @DJI: Could you consider adjusting the limits of the gimbal pitch to the gimbal pitch ranges of the actual drone for the waypoint missions (instead of [-90,0]? Some of your drones can look up, so why not support automated waypoint missions with gimbal angles that can look up?

PS: There is an indication in Waypoint.class that DJI considered this already, but the DJI validation for the gimbal range in waypoint missions is still validating against [-90,0] (which is consistent with the current DJI SDK documentation).

```
public static final float MIN_GIMBAL_PITCH = -135.0F;
public static final float MAX_GIMBAL_PITCH = 45.0F;
```

Thank you for any information on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Mavic 2's possible gimbal pitch range should actually be `[-90, 30]` instead of what it currently is `[-90, 0]`. That is a bug on the the DJI SDK, and will be fixed with the next version, sorry about the inconvenience.

For other aircrafts though, the gimbal pitch range `[-90, 0]` is limited by aircraft firmware. We will keep communicating this with the firmware team and if anything changes, we will update it at https://developer.dji.com/

Comment: DJI firmware team have the plan to improve this. It will come soon.

Comment: Thanks Tim, is the fix only for Mavic 2? Do the Inspire drones also have this limitation?